# Comparing dates based on AM/PM C#

Tags: c#, datetime

How to compare these two using Datetime.compare if AM/PM is specified.

`6/09/2012 9:12:22 AM`  `6/09/2012 9:12:22 PM`   these dates are using "G" format.

Comment: if they are in datetime format, then b.Subtract(a) should give the result in timespan..

Answer (score 1):

Use `DateTime.Compare()` method

like this

```
DateTime d1 = DateTime.Parse("6/09/2012 9:12:22 AM");
DateTime d2 = DateTime.Parse("6/09/2012 9:12:22 PM");

Console.Write(DateTime.Compare(d2, d1));
```

for more info [Go here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x79949f0.aspx)